# What is the correct way to pass multiple arguments to a ruby == operator?

Tags: ruby

I'm a noob trying to do this:

```
    <% if @page[:title] == "Portraits" %>
        <%= render :partial => "/shared/slideshow"  %>  
    <% elsif @page[:title] == "Escapes" %>
        <%= render :partial => "/shared/slideshow"  %>
    <% elsif @page[:title] == "Articulos pa Web" %>
        <%= render :partial => "/shared/slideshow"  %>
    <% end %>
```

There has to be a concise way to do this, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that was a something I was ignoring. Was totally unintentional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid putting the logic you currently have, in a view.

Put this in a helper method instead and use it in the view:

```
def get_partial_to_render
  if ["Portraits","Escapes","Articulos pa Web"].include? @page[:title]
    "shared/slideshow"
  else
    "some_other_template"
  end
end
#Note that the partial should not have a leading `/` in the path to it.
```

And in your view:

```
<%= render :partial => get_partial_to_render  %>
```

Or, if you do not want to render a partial if a name is not in the array:

```
def render_my_partial?
  ["Portraits","Escapes","Articulos pa Web"].include? @page[:title]
end

<%= render :partial => "shared/slideshow" if render_my_partial? %>
```

Note that the `?` is part of the method name. Isn't Ruby wonderful? :D

Answer (score 2):

```
<% if ["Portraits", "Escapes", "Articulos pa Web"].include?(@page[:title])  %>
    <%= render :partial => "/shared/slideshow"  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, but you should avoid putting this kind of logic in the view, as far as possible.